# "drizzle-react-components" import Error for "LoadingContainer"

Tags: solidity, react

I am trying to import `import { LoadingContainer } from 'drizzle-react-components'`

Which I succfully installed with `npm install drizzle-react-components@1.3.0`

It was installed inside the directory `Drizzle\client\node_modules\drizzle-react-components`

However whenever I start the react app I get this error.

```
Failed to compile
    ./node_modules/drizzle-react-components/dist/drizzle-react-components.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'drizzle-react' in 'C:\Users\carl-\Dropbox\Brain\Education\Independent Software Studies\Blockchain\solidity\Drizzle\client\node_modules\drizzle-react-components\dist'
```

This is the complete code from inside `C:\Users\carl-\Dropbox\Brain\Education\Independent Software Studies\Blockchain\solidity\Drizzle\client\src\app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { LoadingContainer } from 'drizzle-react-components'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      //<LoadingContainer>
        <h1>Hello Smart Contracts</h1>
      //</LoadingContainer>
      <h1>Hello Mrs blockchain??</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DrizzleProvider } from 'drizzle-react';
import { LoadingContainer } from 'drizzle-react-components'

const drizzleOptions = {
    contracts: [ContractA]
}

    <DrizzleProvider options={drizzleOptions}>

        <h1>Hello Smart Contracts</h1>
      //</LoadingContainer>
```